# MANIFEST.MF: difference between Main-Class and Start-Class

Tags: java, spring-boot, manifest

In a project I am taking over, I found a Jar file with the following MANIFEST.MF file:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Start-Class: com.xxx.Application
Spring-Boot-Version: 1.2.7.RELEASE
Main-Class: org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher
```

What is the difference between Start-Class and Main-Class?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is a feature of Spring Boot.
Main-Class defines that Spring Boot's `org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher` class will be launched in a first step.

In a second step, `org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher` will launch the `main` method of the class that is given to the Start-Class property - in this case, `com.xxx.Application`.

For details, see https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/executable-jar.html.